# Is it possible to copy sheets over for new budget year, including outbound links?

Tags: smartsheet-api

I have about 75 sheets I have created for our 2019 fiscal year that list budget and actual values for certain company expenses, which link out to a few different summary sheets based on region. I wanted to copy all sheets and blank them out to roll out for the 2020 fiscal year. When I use the Smartsheet API to copy a sheet, it only allows me to copy over inbound links, not outbound ones. Is there a way to copy over outbound links, even to a new sheet?

For reference, I ran the copy sheet code located on the Smartsheet API github page:

```
curl https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/[sheet ID]/copy?include=data,attachments,cellLinks 
-H "Authorization: Bearer [token]"
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
-d '{
  "destinationType": "home",
  "destinationId": null,
  "newName": "newSheetName"
}'
-X POST
```

Answer (score 0):

At this time when making a copy of a sheet, via the API or the UI in your browser, it will only save the inbound cell links. Outbound cell links will be removed with the cell data remaining in place in the newly created sheet. There currently isn't a method to keep the cell links in place via the copy. They would need to be recreated after the copy is done.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!